# legend of spatial objects on top raster background

Tags: r, geospatial, lattice, raster, r-raster

There are good examples how to overlay vector/raster maps on raster layers like [Plotting vector maps overlaid on top of a raster background in R](https://rpubs.com/alobo/vectorOnraster) or [Overlay your raster layer on a background GM layer in R](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16948_38af70d4c22e45df84a2fd69d8698d93.html). But the legends are missing in the merged graphic. In the example `rproblv` has a legend but `migmaplv + rproblv` not.

Is there a easy way to combine two `levelplot` or `spplot` objects and preserve one or both legends in the result?

From [Overlay your raster layer on a background GM layer in R](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16948_38af70d4c22e45df84a2fd69d8698d93.html)

```
library(utils); library(colorRamps); library(rgdal);
library(raster); library(dismo); library(rasterVis)

download.file(
  "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3180464/rprob520.tif", 
  "rprob520.tif", method = "curl")

rprob <- raster("rprob520.tif")
rprobGM <- projectRaster(from = rprob, crs = CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))

migmap <- gmap(x = rprob, type = "hybrid", zoom = 5)

migmaplv <- levelplot(
  migmap, maxpixels = ncell(migmap), 
  col.regions = migmap@legend@colortable, 
  at = 0:255, panel = panel.levelplot.raster, interpolate = TRUE, 
  colorkey = FALSE, margin = FALSE)

rproblv <- levelplot(
  rprobGM, margin = FALSE, contour = TRUE, 
  par.settings = rasterTheme(region = matlab.like(n = 10)), 
  alpha.regions = 0.35, at = (0:10)/10, 
  main = "p(dep > 1kg/m2 per eruption event)")

print(migmaplv + rproblv)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `as.layer` function with `under = TRUE`:

```
rproblv + as.layer(migmaplv, under = TRUE)
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! and now it is no problem to find more examples like https://rpubs.com/daniballari/geovisualizacion ;)